# Visual Studio 2017 High CPU on input (CodeLens)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2017 15.2 (26430.14) and my CPU is between 40-60% on my PC everytime I am writing code. It is really anying since it creates a lag for every character input. Sometimes several seconds. I should state that my PC is not of the most performant kind, but I do have SSD and 16 GB of RAM.

I have Resharper and NCrunch installed, but I have tried to disabled them, but without any result.

The process that spikes the CPU is:

- devenv.exe

And also sometimes:

- ServiceHub.RoslynCodeAnalysisService32.exe

Answer (score 13):

The cause of my problem was something called "CodeLens" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn269218.aspx). This is some kind of realtime analysis of the code giving you references and usage direct within the code. I guess it was a little bit to hard on my weak machine.

When I turned this feature off my lag disappeared instantly. You can turn it off here:

- Options

  - Text Editor

    - All Languages

      - CodeLens

Comment: This seemed to help, but I missed the 'References' annotation above each method. So I re-enabled CodeLens, but turned off all the options except 'References'. Performance is acceptable so far.